# I'm trying example of rowid, but its showing me error. Can anyone give me good example of rowid

Tags: sql, rowid

I have tried the following query, but it is giving me error as invalid column.

Book inventory table contains `titleid` column

```
select rowid, titleid from BookInventory
```

Comment: does the table contain the column rowid?  What sql are you using?

Comment: `rowid` is a pseudo column only valid in Oracle DBMS. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Why most of DBMS (DataBase Management Systems) follow standards, often they introduce own flawors:

rowid is special column in Oracle DBMS

For MSSQL (2008-r2 and onwards) you could use

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY titleid)
```

as equivalent. It is not going to be exactly the same, but can serve the purpose.